# Optimal placement of points that must be a set distance from each other

Tags: geometry

So I have several points a want to place on a 2D plane.

The problem I have is that each point has a specific distance it must be placed from each of the other points. I was wondering if anyone knew of any way to work out a functional placement for all these points that satisfies the distance requirements?

(For example, points a, b, and c. a must be distance 2 from b and 3 from c, and b and c must be 4 apart).

Writing this out I'm realising there must be variations of this that are impossible. The distances are not set in stone, however, and could be varied slightly.

Comment: Not really a programming question, Mathematics has its own exchange.  That said, depending on your requirements, there may be infinite solutions, or none.  Write out the complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may be overkill, but it will work nicely (plus, it's cool):

Consider the problem from a particle simulation perspective: drop your points (hereafter, particles) randomly on to the 2D plane, then perform a mass-spring simulation to regularly distribute the particles in the plane.  To do so, connect adjacent particles (4 or 8 connected neighbors) using springs, and then define the desired distance between points as each spring's *resting length*.

Particles with relative distances greater than this resting length will experience attraction, while those with relative distances smaller than the resting length will experience repulsion. Iterate the physical system a few times, and you should observe the particles to space themselves out regularly, much like birds on a wire (but in 2D).

Google "mass spring simulation" and "Hooke's law". [This link](http://www.unav.es/adi/UserFiles/File/4000002446/3.%20Mass-Spring%20Models.pdf) is good, so are these: [link](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/particle/), [link](http://dmg.caup.washington.edu/pdfs/MArch.Thesis.MikeWeller.2011.pdf), [link](http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Publications/Theses/2010/Czilli_BA_10.pdf), and [link](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos426/lectures/16-particles.pdf). These searches yield a million hits, and you can even find source code.

As you might guess, I do consider this to be a programming question ;)

Comment: Hah, thank you very much, I'll work on throwing together an implementation tomorrow. You sir, get the correct answer.

Comment: I went back to my implementations, and I recall finding this reference helpful: http://itee.uq.edu.au/~comp4201/Particles1.pdf . Keep us posted on your progress: there are lots of "fun" aspects to this, stiffness constants, timesteps, integration methods, etc.

Comment: So I managed to complete my implementation of this. It's in Python and 2D. Works really well too, just wanted to say thanks again. The C++ example was especially useful (always found worked examples the best way to learn).